# How is Tuple<T1,T2>.Create<T1,T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2) implemented?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, tuples

I'm trying to implement a similar method as `Tuple<T1,T2>.Create<T1,T2>(T1 item1, T2 item2)`, but I still have to specify the type parameters whereas Tuple.Create infers them.

I think the definition is right. What am I doing wrong?  Here's my code:

```
public class KeyValuePair<K, V>
{
    public K Key { get; set; }       

    public V Value { get; set; }

    public static KeyValuePair<K, V> Create<K, V>(K key, V value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<K, V> { Key = key, Value = value };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You'll want to create a non-generic version of the class.

```
public class KeyValuePair
{
    public static KeyValuePair<K, V> Create<K, V>(K key, V value)
    {
        return new KeyValuePair<K, V>(key, value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Key and Value properties are read-only which means a kvp is immutable. I made relevant edit.

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out. It's not defined as a static method on the `Tuple<T1,T2>` class, but on the Tuple class.

Comment: @Quintin - Thanks! I didn't realize that virgin ears were present.